# Converting an output to raw string in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, rawstring

my code here i am trying to get the "something-try-composition-library" and version "0.29.2"

```
import re
mystr = "something-try-composition-library version v0.29.2"
new_str = '-'.join(mystr.rsplit('v', 1))
final_str = re.split('\\ version \\b',new_str)
```

but when i am printing the final_str it is returning

```
['something-try-composition-library version -0.29.2']
```

instead of

```
['something-try-composition-library', '-0.29.2']
```

the problem seems to be with the new_str as when i pass mystr it is working fine but yes with the extra v with the version number.

my question is how to convert the output of new_str as raw string.
or if any one have any easy and simple way to get this output

```
['something-try-composition-library', '-0.29.2']
```

will also be great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very specific solution, but for your string it works:

```
mystr = "something-try-composition-library version v0.29.2"
final_str = '-'.join(mystr.rsplit('v', 1)).rsplit(' version ')

output = ['something-try-composition-library', '-0.29.2']
```